# HTML5 website button overlapping

Tags: css, html, button, web

I copied the part of my css for the button, if more is needed ask.

Website: http://younani.com/finalsite/contactus.html

The buttons are overlapping one another, why is that?

```
#left a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #2a07ed);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#ffffff),
        to(#2a07ed));
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}





figure{}

#left a:link { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:visited { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:hover {border: 3px inset #333333; }

#left ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons overlap because the anchor tag is an inline element so the elements are only positioned below each other based on the text content. So the padding causes them to "overlap", if you set

```
display: block;
```

on your `#left a` selector then it should display correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Worked great, Thank you David!